# dom-change not firing up for dom-bind templates

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, web-component

I have a problem where dom-change is not fired (or, is not caught by the evengListener) in a dom-bind template:

```
<body>

  <template id="t" is="dom-bind">
    <h1>Hello, it is:</h1>
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    <input value={{name::input}} />
  </template>

  <script>
    var t = document.querySelector('#t');
    t.addEventListener('dom-change', function(e){
      console.log("READY!");
    })
  </script>

</body>
```

The JSBin is here: http://jsbin.com/wumaso/edit?html,console,output

The console should show "READY!" but it doesn't... any hints?
Please note that the example is basically the same as [the example in the guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind).

Comment: that event is for when children of the tag change, but your <template> doesn't have children, or if it does, they don't change...

Comment: Oh.. of course. How do I know when the template has been stamped and ready to be used?

Comment: @dandavis Actually, the event was indeed meant to be fired -- see Scott's answer below. I had no idea JSBin could interfere so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like JSBin itself is interfering with your application code timing.

If you load your bin in *quiet* mode (removing JSBin machinery) the event fires normally.

http://output.jsbin.com/wumaso/quiet

Comment: But... does that mean that genuine JSBin snippets might not work at all because of this problem?